# мутация при использовании цикла в pl/sql

Tags: sql, база-данных, циклы, plsql, триггер

Здравствуйте. Я знаю, что тема мутации затрагивалась не раз, но все же не могу найти решение своей проблеме.
Мне надо прописать триггер с использованием цикла, который проверяет мэйл людей на наличие значка @ и если его нет, то выводится сообщение, что мэил неправильный.

Что у меня есть:

```
create or replace trigger BeforeUpdate
BEFORE UPDATE on SUPLIER
for each row

declare
email varchar2(28);
counter number;
fin number;
line number := 0;

BEGIN
select count(id_suplier) into counter from suplier;
select count(semail) into fin from suplier;        

LOOP 
line := line + 1;
select semail into email from suplier where id_suplier = line;
if email not like '%@%' then 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Suplier no.' || line || ' has wrong email type');
end if;
exit when line = fin;
end LOOP;
END;
/
```

При активации триггера получается мутация. 
Была идея создать отдельную таблицу под мэилы, но тогда теряется цикл.

Буду благодарна за любую помощь:)

Comment: Вы пишите триггер _for each row_, т.е. для каждой изменяемой строки он вызывается отдельно. Нет никакого смысла в цикле проверять все записи в таблице при модификации каждой из них. Триггер должен проверить только текущую запись, т.е. поле `:new.semail`. никаких циклов и select не надо, за вас все сделает БД

Comment: Вообще построчный триггер _не имеет права_ обращаться к той таблице на которую он написан.

Comment: И кстати, вы в курсе, что если поля semail заполнены у всех строк то count(id_suplier) равен count(semail) и равен количеству записей в таблице. И при этом это число не имеет икакого отношения к ID записей, потому как они могут начинаться не с 1 и идти не подряд. Так что подобный цикл где  бы он ни находился работать не будет.

Comment: @Mike, да, я знаю, но дали, к сожалению, такое задание (чисто в целях изучения синтаксиса) и по условию ID идут с 1 и по порядку

Comment: Тогда делайте это в общем триггере на таблицу, без `for each row`

Comment: А причем здесь триггер? Может функцию или процедуру? Задание в целях трнинга тоже должно иметь смысл и приближаться к реальному.

Answer (score 4):

Как уже было замечено в комментариях, несколько бессмысленно обращаться в построчном триггере ко всей изменяемой таблице. Только к строчке, которая конкретно изменяется посредством `:new` и `:old` псевдозаписей. Циклы, если в них нет обращений к изменяемой таблице, здесь ни причём. Мутация в первом же селекте в коде.

Но если очень хочется, то можно так:

```
create table mails (id number, mail varchar2(64));

insert into mails select * from (
    select 1, 'my@mail.ru' from dual union all 
    select 2, 'other(at)mail.ru' from dual
);

2 rows inserted.

create or replace trigger mails_trig 
before update of mail on mails for each row 
declare
    misformatted number; 
begin
    select count(1) into misformatted
    from mails
    where mail is not null
    and not regexp_like(mail, '\w+@\w+\.\w+')
    ;
end;
/

update mails set mail = '_' || mail where id=1;

SQL Error: ORA-04091: table SH1.MAILS is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "SH1.MAILS_TRIG", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SH1.MAILS_TRIG'
04091. 00000 -  "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"
*Cause:    A trigger (or a user defined plsql function that is referenced in
           this statement) attempted to look at (or modify) a table that was
           in the middle of being modified by the statement which fired it.
*Action:   Rewrite the trigger (or function) so it does not read that table.
```

Как не согласиться, перепишем:

```
create or replace trigger mails_trig 
before update of mail on mails for each row 
declare
    function foundMisformatted return boolean is
        misformatted number; 
        pragma autonomous_transaction;
    begin 
        select count(1) into misformatted
        from mails
        where mail is not null
        and not regexp_like(mail, '\w+@\w+\.\w+')
        ;
        dbms_output.put_line('mails_trig: alrady misformatted emails '||
            misformatted||' - checked by update row'||:old.id||'/'||:old.mail);
        return misformatted>0;
    end;
begin
    if foundMisformatted then
        --raise_application_error(-20009, 'misformatted mails.mail found');
        --или, что-то более жизненое - пускай неопытный коллега денёк ошибку поищет
        dbms_output.put_line('mails_trig: warning: misformatted mails.mail found');
        :new.mail := :old.mail;
        return;
    end if;
    -- do anything
end;
/

update mails set mail = '_' || mail where id=1;

mails_trig: alrady misformatted emails 1 - checked by update row 1/my@mail.ru  
mails_trig: warning: misformatted mails.mail found
```